# What will be the value of an element in a form if it doesnt exist in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a divider with a element from an HTML form... (text element) 
I change the div css display to none with javascript
what will be the value of the element if the divider is set to display none 
??

What will the value be if the element never existed in the first place ?

Comment: Wait, so is it a `div` or a text `input` or `textarea`?

Comment: its a text input inside a div which i change the display to none with javascript

Comment: Regarding your second question about an element that never existed, do you mean what will happen if you try to access the value in your server-side code (when the form is submitted)? If so, that may depend on which language you are using. If your server-side code is Java I'd expecting missing request parameters to be null, but other languages may give some other value.

Comment: what will happen when i try to access it from the client side in javascript?

Comment: How are you trying to access it? I would normally use `document.getElementById()`, which will return `null` if there is no element with the Id that you pass to it.

Comment: var elementValue = document.forms[""].elements[""].value;

Comment: I would expect `document.forms[""].elements["nonexistentId"]` to be `undefined`, so it won't have a `value` property and you'll probably get an error. Which, depending on your browser settings, may mean the script simple stops without telling you why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be whatever the 'value' attribute of the form element is.  The CSS styling has no affect on the form values sent back to the server.

```
<form action="post_to_me.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="hideme" value="Initial value" style="display:none;" />
 <div style="display:none;">
  <input name="hideme2" type="text" value="Initial value" />
 </div>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The form will post with both hideme and hidem2 equal to "Initial value"

Comment: Form elements don't have a value attribute, it is optional for most form controls.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a form element isn't affected by whether or not it is rendered. It will be the same as what it is when `display` is not `none`.

Answer (score 0):

If the containing div element is hidden the value of the input element within it will not change. FYI. If the element is hidden it doesnt mean it doesnt not exist in the dom.